# multiple values must have the same value within one table SQL

Tags: sql

I have one table, in which there can be one or many values to a first column.

If there are multiple same values within first column, I would need to find those, which has at least 2 different values in another column.

Example table CARS:

[image: CAR COLOR BMW black Honda brown BMW red Mercedes yellow Honda brown Honda brown]

So, the result of the query would be:

[image]

Because there are more honda`s but all of them have the same value of second attribute, I am not interested of those.
I need to find only those, which has the same attribute 1 with different attribute 2

Hopefully it`s explained well, if not I can provide more info :)

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use `exists`:

```
select t.*
from t
where exists (select 1 from t t2 where t2.car = t.car and t2.color <> t2.color);
```

Comment: seems it`s working perfectly, thank you :)